# Call a PHP function only when form submitted

Tags: php, forms

I start by saying: not a php backend dev here.

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="myForm" autocomplete="off">
    <textarea  name="newContent" class="form-control" rows="10"><?php the_content(); ?></textarea>
    <p class="read-more"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Read More</button></p>
    <input id="update_content" type="submit" value="Update">
    <?php
        $post = array(
            'ID' => $id,
            'post_content' => $_POST['newContent']
        );
        wp_update_post($post, true);
    ?>
</form>
```

Now that is on the page, therefore each time I am loading it, `wp_update_post($post, true);` is run.

What would it be the easiest way to run that on click on `<input id="update_content" type="submit" value="Update">` and not on each page load?

Comment: So if I understand correct, you're trying to execute the php applet there without any kind of page reload? [edit] I'm typing up an answer, just wanna clarify

Comment: @dGRAMOP not really, I don't want to use ajax and I don't want to use an external file, I wanted to run `wp_update_post($post, true);` when I click the submit, which refreshes the page. I am looking at                 `if(isset($_POST)){
           wp_update_post($post, true);
          }` but isn't working

Comment: oooh, so you're trying to provide two different functionalities for the same PHP file endpoint depending on GET or POST?

Comment: php code has to be run on the server, you will need ajax to do that.

Comment: just move your PHP outside the form and check if `$_POST['newContent']` is not empty before running that piece of code

Comment: @xanadev no, he wants the page to reload, but he wants GET and POST to be handled with the same PHP file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, give your input a name:

```
<input name="submit" value="Update">
```

Then in your code, assuming PHP 7+:

```
if ('Update' === ($_POST['submit'] ?? false)) {
    wp_update_post($post, true);
}
```

How it works: when you click a button of type submit in the browser, the browser packages up the *named* input elements and sends them over the wire. The web server unravels the HTTP message and sends them to PHP, which makes them available in the associative array (aka dictionary) named `$_POST`. (Or if the method is GET, then `$_GET`). You can then check this array for the expected keys and their values.

As an aside, you don't strictly need to name your button. You could also do:

```
if (count($_POST)) {
    ...
}
```

which asserts there is at least one key value pair in the posted data.

You might also consider using `var_dump('<pre>', $_POST)` as a diagnostic aid.

Finally, it's not clear to me where your `$id` comes from, but that needs to be set properly, too.

Comment: might as well include the array inside the if.

Comment: @hungrykoala I'd rather not make that assumption. The OP may be using `$post` (with a null value of `post_content`) elsewhere and not shown in this sample.

Comment: @bishop thanks a lot, what if I have 2 forms? In that case we'd have to POST, so probably the `if('Update..` part if the correct, basically I should writing as many as per each submit button on each form I might have, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, if you have two forms you need two `if`, with each one checking for the name of the submitted button. It's for this reason that I prefer the _explicit_ test of which button was clicked, vs the implicit `count($_POST)` or `'POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` from @dGRAMOP's answer.

Answer (score 2):

@bishop's solution is quick and easy, but I thought i'd add this:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']
```

let's you determine the method of the request.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST")
{
 wp_update_post($post, true); 
}
```

This is arguably the "correct way", and would pass even if the post body is empty, although our answers are functionally the same

Comment: Right on. Great suggestion!

Comment: thank you, accepted the other one as I have more than one form but I get how this work, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Put variables and function here
}
```